# Zeckendorf with Negative Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Zeckendorf : *Every positive integer N can be expressed uniquely as a sum of distinct non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers*

I was wondering if this theorem can be applied with the extended Fibonacci numbers, and especially I am looking for a way to **find the Zeckendorf-like representation of $ N $, with Fibonacci numbers $ F_n $ having only negative indexes**. (First for $ N \in \mathbb{N} $ then maybe $ N \in \mathbb{Z} $)

[Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZeckendorfRepresentation.html) states that this theorem only applies on positive numbers but do not says if Fibonacci numbers can be negative.
Online [Zeckendorf Representation](https://www.dcode.fr/zeckendorf-representation) pages show positive indexes only and mostly use Binet's formula.

I've read that Binet's formula can be applied to generalized Fibonacci numbers ([Proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler-Binet_Formula/Negative_Index)), but it does not prove that Zeckendorf theorem can be used as well.

**EDIT :** I missed a paragraph in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem#Representation_with_negafibonacci_numbers) called Representation with Negafibonacci numbers that states this Zeckendorf-like representation exists and is unique. I probably can use [NegaFibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NegaFibonacci_coding) coding method to find the indexes.

Comment: Wikipedia's page on Zeckendorf's theorem states that the result you seek is true. I think you can adapt the proof proposed on the webpage to the negative case (which is a simple inductive argument)

Comment: The Binet formula has another purpose than finding Zeckendorf Representations , namely to directly calculate $F_n$. (I am not the downvoter). If I understand the question right, you are looking for representations where negative indeces are allowed so we won't have uniqueness in general anymore, did I understand it right ?

Comment: OK, I found the Wikipedia paragraph, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem its source is not available anymore (I'm gonna check archives). I was mainly looking for the existence and the method to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative fibbonacci numbers run as $F(-n)=F(n)$ for odd $n$ and $F(-n)=-F(n)$ for even $n$.

So we get for fibonacci numbers

```
 -21  13  -8   5  -3   2  -1   1
                          -1
                  -3           1
                  -3
                  -3      -1
          -8           2       1
          -8           2
          -8       t0 12
  -21          5       2       1
  -21     -8       -3     -1
```

So yes, all of the natural numbers can be expressed as a sum of non-consecutive fibonacci numbers of negative index.

It ought be a straight-forward conversion from the positive to negative schema.

```
  eg  -21            5     2      1
       21           -5    -2     -1
           13   8   -5    -2    -1
           13           3 -2     -1
           13
```

It's possible to go both ways, and there is a carry rule to prevent adjacent columns being filled with more than one counter.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/30-2/bunder.pdf) that proves the existence and shows a method

*(we prove that) every integer can be represented uniquely as a sum of nonconsecutive Fibonacci numbers Fi where i < 0 and we specify an algorithm that leads to this representation*